# django-smart-selects not working properly with jquery.formset.js django

Tags: jquery, django, django-smart-selects

I am a beginner in `django`. I have created a form using `inlineformset_factory` with j`query.formset.js` library for increasing rows. The price field uses `django-smart-selects` where depending on the product selected, the available prices are populated in the price field. Everything works fine for the first row but for any other new row added, the `django-smart-selects` price field no longer works. Also, when I delete the first row and re-add it, the `django-smart-selects` no longer works. I want the price field to keep working on each row depending on what product is selected. Below are my codes:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    product_name = models.TextField(blank=False, unique=True)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(_(u'Selling Price'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
    objects = models.Manager()
        
class Price(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Item Name')
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(_(u'Price'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))], blank=False, default=0)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.TextField(blank=False, unique=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Item Name')
    price = ChainedForeignKey(Price, chained_field="product_id", chained_model_field="product_id", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True, default=0)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

**forms.py**

```
class InvoiceItemForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvoiceItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id:
            self.fields['price'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        fields = [ 'invoice', 'quantity', 'product_id', 'price']

InvoiceItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceItem, form=InvoiceItemForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class InvoiceCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ChainedSelectFormViewMixin, CreateView):
    model = Invoice
    form_class = InvoiceForm
    template_name = "website1app/invoice_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('invoice_list')
    success_message = 'New invoice successfully added'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InvoiceCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['items'] = InvoiceItemFormset(self.request.POST, prefix='invoiceitem_set')
        else:
            context['items'] = InvoiceItemFormset(prefix='invoiceitem_set')
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['items']
        self.object = form.save()
        if self.object.id != None:
            if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = self.object
                formset.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def test_func(self):
        return True
```

**invoice_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base_template.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}


{% block title %}

{% if object %}
Update Invoice {{ object }}
{% else %}
Add New Sales Invoice
{% endif %}

{% endblock title %}

{% block main_content %}

<form method="POST" id="invoiceForm">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.media.js }}

  {% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}


  <div class="row" style="border-top:5px; border-top-style:outset; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 callout callout-info">
      {{ items.management_form }}
      <div class="text-center">PRODUCT LIST</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><strong>Product</strong></div>
        <div class="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
        <div class="col"><strong>Price</strong></div>
      </div>
      {% for item in items %}
      <div class="form-group row items-group">
        <div class="col">{{ item.product_id | add_class:"form-control"}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{ item.quantity | add_class:"form-control"}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{ item.price | add_class:"form-control"}}</div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>


  <div style="text-align: center;">
    {% if object %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Record">
    {% else %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</form>

<hr>

{% endblock main_content %}


{% block custom_js %}
<script>
  $(function() {

    $(".items-group").formset({
        prefix: '{{ items.prefix }}',
        deleteText: "<div class='btn btn-danger btn-circle'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></div>",
        addText: "<div class='btn btn-success btn-circle' style='text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px;'><i class='fas fa-plus'></i></div>",
      })

  })
</script>
{% endblock custom_js %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nima Derakhshanjan